# How do I mount an Windows SMB server as a writeable volume on Lion?

Tags: macos, mount, smb

When trying to mount an Windows file service over SMB (Samba) in Lion I get the following error when trying to write:

```
  % touch testfile.txt          
  touch: testfile.txt: Read-only file system
```

This happens both when connecting via Finder or mounting in the Terminal.

```
mount_smbfs -f 777 -d 777 //david.hall@fileserver1/wwwroot remote
Password for fileserver1:
```

I have no problem reading the files and my user do have permission to write to the directories in question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume its windows server as you're mounting a wwwroot. Ensure your user david.hall has file permission access to the correct hierarchy not just share permissions. This is usually why stuff mounts as read-only from the win side.

OS X just mounts the share as normal unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Add force user to the share in smb.conf.  (Change to the appropriate user name)...

```
force user = root
```